# SQL Joins: Select status of reviews submitted by employees and also the list of employees who have not submitted the review for each year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

For each year, for each employee, I want to list the status of the review that employee had submitted, or "not initiated" in case employee did not submit review for that year.

It's kind of difficult to express the question in words therefore I would try to explain it by giving example:

```
create table #employees 
(
empid int,
name varchar(100)
)

Create table #review
(
empid int,
ryear int,
status varchar(20)
)

insert into #review values(1,2016,'S2')
insert into #review values(2,2016,'S2')
insert into #review values(2,2017,'S1')
insert into #review values(3,2017,'S2')



insert into #employees values(1,'jack')
insert into #employees values(2,'mack')
insert into #employees values(3,'rack')
insert into #employees values(4,'tack')
```

**Wrong Query**

```
select a.empid
      ,a.name
      ,b.ryear
      ,case isnull(b.status,'')
           when ''
               then 'Not Initiated'
           else status
       end as status
from #employees as a
    left join #review as b
        on a.empid = b.empid
           and b.ryear in(select distinct
                                 ryear
                          from #review
                         );--something like that
```

**Expected Result:**

```
+-------+------+-------+----------------+
| empid | name | ryear |     status     |
+-------+------+-------+----------------+
|     1 | jack |  2016 | S2             |
|     1 | jack |  2017 | not initiated  |
|     2 | mack |  2016 | S2             |
|     2 | mack |  2017 | S1             |
|     3 | rack |  2016 | not initieated |
|     3 | rack |  2017 | S2             |
|     4 | tack |  2016 | Not Initiated  |
|     4 | tack |  2017 | Not Initiated  |
+-------+------+-------+----------------+
```

Comment: *It's kind of difficult to express the question in words therefore I would try to explain it by giving example*  --  **Thank you**,  this is exactly how all questions should be asked.

Comment: @iamdave Are you being sarcastic?

Comment: Not at all, your question is perfect! :)

Comment: @iamdave oh well thanks

Comment: It's not polite, but he has a point. Anyways, if I'm getting you right, for each year, for each employee, you will list the status of the review that he submitted, or "not initiated" if he didn't, correct?

Comment: @KtX2SkD that is correct. I did not mean to be rude its just that English is not my first language, sometimes i find it difficult to express a problem in words.

Comment: It's not mine too, you'd be surprised what's mine :)  Later though, could you please add the agreed-on description of the problem into the question itself, rephrase as needed.

Comment: @KtX2SkD done..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a cross join on your sub query

```
select a.empid
      ,a.name
      ,c.ryear
      ,isnull(b.status,'Not Initiated') as status
from #employees as a
    cross join(select distinct
                      ryear
               from #review
              ) as c
    left join #review as b
            on b.ryear = c.ryear
            and a.empid = b.empid
order by a.empid, ryear
```

Comment: With no 'order by' statement, the results are not quite as expected.

Comment: Also, using the cross join on a subquery SQL has to fetch this data multiple times, thus using a CTE is more efficient.

Comment: That's not actually true, the query optimiser in this case treats the subquery and cte the same.

Comment: Hi Simon, did a bit of googling and it seems you are right regarding the way the optimizer processes both subquery and cte. However, it is noted that CTE is used to make your code more readable.

Comment: A CTE is useful to encapsulate a query if used multiple times, in this simple case a subquery is perfectly acceptable. I agree though for more complex queries, CTEs can help make the entire statement more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one using a common table expression;
It also supports multiple reviews in the same year for an employee.

```
WITH X AS
(SELECT distinct ryear FROM #review)
SELECT a.empid, a.name, X.ryear, isnull(b.status,'Not initiated')
  FROM X as x
  LEFT
  JOIN #employees as a
    ON 1=1
  LEFT
  JOIN #review as b
    ON a.empid = b.empid
   AND b.ryear = x.ryear
 ORDER 
    BY a.empid,x.ryear
```

Comment: query may be giving correct output and it may not be hard coded,but in real life i never write such query.I will find a way to avoid distinct and order by on 2 column.So imagine in real life,there will be lot of change in your query.

Answer (score 1):

This supposedly supports the presence of more than one review by the same employee in the same year:

```
SELECT Employees.empid, Employees.[name], ReviewYears.[Value]
     , [Status] = ISNULL(LatestReviews.[status], 'Not Initiated')
FROM #employees AS Employees
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ryear AS [Value] FROM #review) AS ReviewYears -- We need some source of years, hopefully there are no missing years here.
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT empid, ryear, [status]
             , RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY empid, ryear ORDER BY STATUS DESC) -- Per employee and year, we'll take only one status, hopefully we can order by statuses.
        FROM #review
    ) AS T
WHERE RN = 1 -- Refer to comments at creation of RN.
) AS LatestReviews ON LatestReviews.empid = Employees.empid AND LatestReviews.ryear = ReviewYears.[Value] -- Refer to comments at creation of RN.
ORDER BY Employees.empid ASC, ReviewYears.[Value] ASC
```

Comment: Hi KtX2SkD, as commented on Simon's answer, using the subquery (and cross join on it), SQL has to do multiple loads of the 'ryear' data. By using a CTE (see my answer), only 1 fetch occurs, thus this is better for performance.

Comment: @Karel, thank you for remarking that. I myself barely know a thing about performance even though I tried a few times to get into it. My seniors and the tools are of almost no help either >.>

Comment: Actually, seeing Simon's comment on his answer, and googling a bit around, it seems that subquery vs CTE does not have an actual impact as the SQL Optimizer would process both equally. However, it is noted that CTE can be used to make your SQL easier to read.